# Passing $('.class').each a function as arugment fails to run function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code that works perfectly

```
$('.picture').each(function(index) { 
  hideYourself(index);
});
```

However, when I try

```
$('.picture').each(hideYourself(index));
```

it doesn't run hideYourself. I thought it was maybe because I wasn't defining `index` but I don't define it when I pass it an anonymous function. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cirsca/pen/XdmawO) of the whole program.

I know this might be a silly thing to be worried about but I am just confused on why passing `.each` a named function fails but passing it an anonymous function that calls my named function it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.picture').each(hideYourself);
```

Comment: Wow. It was that easy. in 11 minutes I'll accept your answer! can you explain why it is this way or know of a good resource I can read up on why it's this way?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ When you pass `hideYourself` function as argument of `each` method it is already get index as first param when it is called.

Comment: thank you! I can now finally use my functions without having to use anonymous functions to call them!

Answer (score 2):

Because each take one parameter function as argument but you actually invoking function using `hideYourSelf(index)` it invoked the function and returns the function return value as parameter to each.

You can achieve it as:

```
$('.picture').each(hideYourself);
```

or another way to achieve the same behavior is:

```
$('.picture').each(hideYourself());

function hideYourself(){
  return function(index){
     //hide here
  }
}
```

first way is easy and better.